# Fastest way to draw many textured quads in OpenGL 3+

Tags: opengl

Since GL_QUADS has been removed from OpenGL 3.1 and above, what is the fastest way to draw lots of quads without using it? I've tried several different methods (below) and have ranked them on speed on my machine, but I was wondering if there is some better way, since the fastest way still seems wasteful and inelegant. I should mention that in each of these methods I'm using VBOs with interleaved vertex and texture coordinates, since I believe that to be best practice (though I may be wrong). Also, I should say that I can't reuse any vertices between separate quads because they will have different texture coordinates.

1. glDrawElements with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP using a primitive restart index, so that the index array looks like {0, 1, 2, 3, PRI, 4, 5, 6, 7, PRI, ...}. This takes in the first 4 vertices in my VBO, treats them as a triangle strip to make a rectangle, and then treats the next 4 vertices as a separate strip. The problem here is just that the index array seems like a waste of space. The nice thing about GL_QUADS in earlier versions of OpenGL is that it automatically restarts primitives every 4 vertices. Still, this is the fastest method I can find.
2. Geometry shader. I pass in 1 vertex for each rectangle and then construct the appropriate triangle strip of 4 vertices in the shader. This seems like it would be the fastest and most elegant, but I've read, and now seen, that geometry shaders are not that efficient compared to passing in redundant data.
3. glDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLES. I just draw every triangle independently, reusing no vertices.
4. glMultiDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, an array of all multiples of 4 for the "first" array, and an array of a bunch of 4's for the "count" array. This tells the video card to draw the first 4 starting at 0, then the first 4 starting at 4, and so on. The reason this is so slow, I think, is that you can't put these index arrays in a VBO.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a definitive answer here, the performance could easily be different from one gpu to another or even one driver to another.

Comment: 1. No, 2. Geometry shaders are not meant to be used by themselves, they perform best when the output is saved to a buffer and reused, 3. Maybe, 4. Maybe, 5. VBOs. Fast in graphics is often not the most elegant, but the difference may be large enough to make up for it.

Comment: What is 5? I'm already using VBOs for everything that I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've covered all the typical good ways, but I'd like to suggest a few less typical ones that I suspect may have higher performance.  Based on the wording of the question, I shall assume that you're trying to draw an m*n array of tiles, and they all need different texture coordinates.

- A geometry shader is not the right tool to add and remove vertices.  It's capable of doing that, but it's really intended for cases when you actually change the number of primitives you're rendering dynamically (e.g. shadow volume generation).  If you just want to draw a whole bunch of adjacent different primitives with different texture coordinates, I suspect the absolute fastest way would be to use tessellation shaders.  Just pass in a single quad and have the tessellator compute texture coordinates procedurally.
- A similar and more portable method would be to look up each quad's texture coordinate.  This is trivial: say you're drawing 50x20 quads, you would have a 50x20 texture that stores all your texture coordinates.  Tap this texture in your vertex program (or perhaps more efficiently in your geometry program) and send the result in a varying to the fragment program for actual rendering.

Note that in both of the above cases, you can reuse vertices.  In the first method, the intermediate vertices are generated on the fly.  In the second, the vertices' texture coordinates are replaced in the shader with cached values from the texture.

Comment: But would a tessellation shader work if the quads are not adjacent?

Comment: No, to my knowledge it would not.  As you get more and more optimized, the work required gets even more complicated.  But, you should ask yourself whether you even *need* these optimizations.  It pays most to get the code working in the first place with *any* method.